# Set the Index of each object, of an nested object into an property

Tags: javascript, object, nested

Good morning !

Does anyone know how i can insert the index of each object of a nested object into an property ?

Something like this:

```
const myObj = 
{
  "@type": "someType",
  A: [
    {
      "@type": "someType0",
      order: "DESC",
      myIndex: 0
    },
    {
      "@type": "someType1",
      order: "DESC",
      myIndex: 1
    },
    {
      "@type": "someType2",
      order: "DESC",
      myIndex: 2
    }
  ],
  B: [],
};
```

Comment: You want to insert `myIndex` right?

Comment: Thank you everybody !
Appreciated all the help !

Comment: @LainIwakura Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer which best addresses your question.  We love them upvotes :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a recursive approach and add for all arrays an index.

```js
function setIndex(object) {
    Object.values(object).forEach(v => {
        if (Array.isArray(v)) {
            v.forEach((o, i) => {
                o.index = i;
                setIndex(o);
            });
        }
    });
}

const object = { "@type": "someType", A: [{ "@type": "someType0", order: "DESC" }, { "@type": "someType1", order: "DESC" }, { "@type": "someType2", order: "DESC" }], B: [] };

setIndex(object);

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nina, do you have a blog or something? Your answers are always very succinct and well thought through. To the point where I go out of my way to look them over, even on questions that I've also answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .map function to alter the objects within array.

```js
const myObj = 
{
  "@type": "someType",
  A: [
    {
      "@type": "someType0",
      order: "DESC"      
    },
    {
      "@type": "someType1",
      order: "DESC"      
    },
    {
      "@type": "someType2",
      order: "DESC"      
    }
  ],
  B: [],
};

const newA = myObj.A.map((item,index) => {
  item.myIndex = index;
  return item;
})

console.log(newA);
```

CodePen link: https://codepen.io/bergur/pen/rrdyKX?editors=0010

If you wanna loop through all the properties of myObj you can use `Object.keys(myObj)` and then go through them and alter them one by one.

Comment: Why mapping at all if you mutate the objects?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that iterating over the array and assigning `i` (current index of iteration) to the object property, like `myObj.A.forEach((d, i) => d.myIndex = i);`, where `d` - is current item, and `i` - is current index.

```js
const myObj = 
{
  "@type": "someType",
  A: [
    {
      "@type": "someType0",
      order: "DESC"
    },
    {
      "@type": "someType1",
      order: "DESC"
    },
    {
      "@type": "someType2",
      order: "DESC"
    }
  ],
  B: [],
};

myObj.A.forEach((d, i) => d.myIndex = i);
console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `Object.keys` or `Object.values` and `Array.forEach` to achieve this.  Using your 'myObject' variable as a starting point, something like this...

**Using `Object.keys`**

```
/* loop through keys of 'myObject' */
Object.keys(myObject).forEach(function(key) {
    /* check that 'myObject[key] is an Array &&
       loop through items in each 'myObject[key]'
       to add unique 'myIndex' property */
    Array.isArray(myObject[key]) && myObject[key].forEach(function(obj, idx) {
        obj.myIndex = idx;
    });
});
```

**Using `Object.values`**

```
/* loop through 'myObject' property values */
Object.values(myObject).forEach(function(val) {
    /* check 'val' is an Array &&
       loop through each item in 'val' 
       to add unique 'myIndex' property */
    Array.isArray(val) && val.forEach(function(obj, idx) {
        obj.myIndex = idx;
    });
});
```

Hope that helps. :-D

- [Array.forEach @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Array.isArray @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)
- [Object.keys @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [Object.values @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)